# Passing Object to Fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to pass an ArrayList to a fragment as arguments but the argument seems to be empty.
This is my code of the mainActivity where I create and launch the fragment, which btw works.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myeventListRefImages;  //has data
 imageFragment = new ImageMyEventRefFragment();
 fragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentId);
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_image) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            getIntent().putExtra("mERImageList", myeventListRefImages); //working
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //doesn’t work
            bundle.putSerializable("mERImageList", myeventListRefImages);//doesn’t work
            imageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
[…]
        }
```

So far, I only get to manage it with putExtra but in that case, the extra never seems to be empty later on which is kind annoying in case I want to skip the if argument  :( 
That’s the code of my fragment:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle args = getArguments();//doesn’t work //empty at all
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();//works
    if (args != null) {
System.out.println("Args!");
}
}
```

Any idea? I event cant debug the fragment to check the value of the getArugments comment there the app just crashes, but when I run it normally I can use System out commands.